# jqgrid: update a cell value with out pressing enter

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

Im using jqgrid, in inline editing, afetr the user edits a particular cell value he needs to press 'Enter' button for updating, but i need it to be updated directly when the user leaves the cell..

Jquery code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var lastsel;
        var colind = 2;
        jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
            url: '/Home/GetStudents/',
            datatype: 'json',

            mtype: 'POST',
            colNames: ['StudentID', 'FirstName', 'LastName', 'Email'],
            colModel: [
      { name: 'StudentID', sortable: false, key: true },
      { name: 'FirstName', key: true },
      { name: 'LastName', sortable: false, key: true },
      { name: 'Email', width: 200, sortable: false, key: true}],
            cmTemplate: { align: 'center', editable: true },
            pager: '#pager',
            width: 750,
            rowNum: 15,
            rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
            sortname: 'StudentID',
            sortorder: "asc",
            viewrecords: true,
            caption: ' My First JQgrid',

            onSelectRow: function (StudentID)
            //  onCellSelect:function(StudentID)
            {


                if (StudentID != lastsel) {

                    jQuery('#list').jqGrid('restoreRow', lastsel);
                    jQuery('#list').jqGrid('editRow', StudentID, true);
                    // jQuery('#list').jqGrid('editCell', StudentID, colind, true);
                    lastsel = StudentID;

                }
            },






            editurl: '/Home/About/',
            //                data: { get_param: selectedDescription },
            caption: "jQgrid Sample"

        });

        jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid', "#pager", { edit: false, add: false, del: false });
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recommend you to implement such behavior because it can produce validation errors. If the user just start to type something of to change some text the entered data could be still wrong. Automatically saving of the data after short time interval can follow to attempt of saving absolutely wrong data.

If the user for example would press wrong key (like a letter in the field where only numbers are allowed) the error will accrue during saving of the data.

Moreover if the user start typing of some wrong information (for example he can delete by mistake some long text from some cell) the saving of the information don't permit the rollback. Standard inline editing implementation support <kbd>Esc</kbd> key additionally to <kbd>Enter</kbd>. I find support of <kbd>Esc</kbd> key very important.

So I can repeat, that I don't recommend you to implement the behavior which you describe in the question.

One additional option which you should consider is the usage of cell editing instead of inline editing. I personally prefer inline editing, but it's the matter of the taste.